# Mystery with Oracle inactive sessions JDBC connections and application slowness

Tags: oracle, jdbc, websphere, database-connection, connection-pooling

Pardon me for my limited knowledge of Oracle Database.

following is scenario
I am currently working on application where my web application is deployed on 4 profiles of Websphere application server. these 4 profiles can together handle load of 600 users.

all these 4 profiles are pointing to single Oracle Database. in normal scenario we observe that on an average nearly 100 inactive sessions exists(yes i am aware of inactive session =sessions which are not performing any activity at that moment) but in certain scenarios we observed that these inactive session count goes up more than 150 and users are complaining slowness.

i would like to appreciate if someone help me by providing pointers for following queries
1]how to calculate require oracle session count based on connection pools considering above scenario of 4 profiles

2]how to ensure even if my oracle inactive session count reach beyond peak limit (in this case 150) application will not have any impact from slowness point of view.

Comment: Which version of WAS are you using? What are JDBC connection pool parameters for Oracle database (connection timeout, max connections, min connections, reap time, unused timeout)?

Comment: we are using WAS 6.1. connection timeout 3 min